# LINQ Object Referance not set

Tags: linq, object, reference

I am getting an "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" error when searching for an item (on Guid) that is selected from a datagrid. I have checked that the item does return the Guid correctly (by writing it to a label on the page), however in my linq query (i assume) i am comparing incorrectly.

ctx is the domaindatasource, I know the element im trying to remove exists.

```
      private void medItemRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            MedicineInventory M = (MedicineInventory)medicineInventoryDataGrid.SelectedItem;
            Guid Mid = M.MedicineInventoryId;
            MedicineInventory toRemove = new MedicineInventory();
            toRemove = (from a in ctx.MedicineInventories where (a.MedicineInventoryId == Mid) select a).Single();
            ctx.MedicineInventories.Remove(toRemove);
            ctx.SubmitChanges();

        }
```

Comment: Can you specify in which line the code breaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your code as follows:

```
private void medItemRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    MedicineInventory M = (MedicineInventory)medicineInventoryDataGrid.SelectedItem;
    Guid Mid = M.MedicineInventoryId;
    MedicineInventory toRemove = (from a in ctx.MedicineInventories where (a != null && a.MedicineInventoryId == Mid) select a).SingleOrDefault();
    if (toRemove != null){
       ctx.MedicineInventories.Remove(toRemove);
       ctx.SubmitChanges();
    }
    else { .... } // code if toRemove is null

 }
```

Comment: I now get a "Sequence contains no elements" error... Although i know that the element from the datagrid does exist.

Comment: I've done an edit where you could use `SingleOrDefault`. It returns null if the row isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is happening because you're creating a new `MedicineInventory`.

Replace this:

```
MedicineInventory toRemove = new MedicineInventory();
```

With this:

```
var toRemove = ctx.MedicineInventories.Single(mi => mi.MedicineInventoryId == Mid);
```

**Update:**

When it retuns the error message *"Sequence contains no elements"* it's because EF could not find a row in the database with the same Guid you're using in the `where` clause. In this case and to avoid an exception, you can try this line of code:

```
var toRemove = ctx.MedicineInventories.SingleOrDefault(
                                                  mi => mi.MedicineInventoryId == Mid);
```

then use an `if` to delete if it's not `NULL`:

```
if(toRemove != null)
{
    ctx.MedicineInventories.Remove(toRemove);

    ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
else
{
    // Only you know what to do! :-)
}
```

> [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) returns the only element of a sequence, or a default
>   value (`NULL` in this case) if the sequence is empty; this method
>   throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.

---

Note: the way you're comparing the Guids is correct because `==` is overloaded on Guid so you don't need to compare the string representations.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.op_equality%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Y474

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your table on the database has a `MedicineInventory` with the same Guid you're passing in the query? Put a breakpoint in the line of code I mention in my answer and take note of the Guid and compare it with the one you have on the database side.

Comment: I am yes. They both have the same Guid.

Is there perhaps something that i need to change in the metadata that's inhibiting the removal?

Comment: I have no idea... if both are Guids the LINQ query should return that single row without problem provided that the Guids are really the same. Make sure your connection string related to the context `ctx` is pointing to the correct database too.

Answer (score 0):

Is a null at any point?

```
toRemove = (from a in ctx.MedicineInventories where (a != null && a.MedicineInventoryId == Mid) select a).Single();
```